# Can I use case inside where clause to compare with a column value

Tags: sql, oracle

Assume limit_exceeded is a boolean-like column that has 1 if the limit 10 was exceeded and 0 if not. I'm passing a number to get the corresponding risk_code based on if the limit was exceeded or not.

I tried this but gives me an error:

```
DECLARE
  temp   VARCHAR2(10);
  my_num NUMBER;
BEGIN
  my_num := 80;
  SELECT risk_code
    INTO temp
    FROM risk_table
   WHERE limit_exceeded = (CASE WHEN my_num > 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0) ;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(temp);
END;
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: There's an END missing for CASE (CASE WHEN my_num > 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 **END**) (if that's an error you're talking about).

Comment: @Littlefoot yes that was the error! thanks a lot I don't know how did I miss it :')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`SIGN()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SIGN.html#GUID-08B75521-B5F5-4658-A005-4B4441C82945) function along with `DECODE()` as another option such as

```
SELECT risk_code
  INTO temp
  FROM risk_table
 WHERE limit_exceeded = DECODE(SIGN(my_num - 10),1,0);
```

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to unpack the `case` expression into standard `and`/`or` conditions:

```
declare
    temp   varchar2(10);
    my_num number := 80;
begin
    select risk_code into temp
    from   risk_table
    where  limit_exceeded = 0
    or     (my_num > 10 and limit_exceeded = 1);

    dbms_output.put_line(temp);
end;
```